# Mobile optimisation of rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile

I have a website at http://bit.ly/1h3HLVE

There are two issues I am trying to resolve regarding viewing the website on mobile devices.

1. The dropdown boxes in the top navbar do not work on mobile viewing (with my iphone anyway)
2. When I load the website the first time it is zoomed in on my mobile, and I need to zoom out to see it properly. I'd like to find a way to have it automatically open at the right size for the mobile device.

Can anyone help with either of these?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called responsive design, the easiest way would be learn a little about [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), Bootstrap is framework for design, there is a gem for rails called [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) for easy integration, with this you can set different behaviours for different devices (this is one of the functionalities of bootstrap), you can hide for example your `navbar` in mobile devices and show another smaller in mobile. Bootstrap also has responsive adaptive support for images and tables, that it will change according to the width of the device dynamically.

Of course, if you are hiding items they will still loading to your site so eventually it could be a little hard to loading, you can use [browser gem](https://github.com/fnando/browser) then, this one allow you to have different behaviors for different devises with conditionals(mobile? desktop? e.g.) and also let you have different views for each one.

Check both of them, is a good place too start and there is lots of guides for those, regards.

Comment: thanks, I've used bootstrap before but will check out the browser gem. Much appreciated.

Comment: the other way is to make the responsive code in your css, but that could be really hard, or changing it with javascript, a lot more harder in my opinion, that's why i suggest bootstrap, but there are lots of responsive frameworks, you just need something that manage the sizes according to the widths, returning to bootstrap, excluding all the design, with the grid system you can do lots of stuffs, you can also "preselect" the items you need so you don't have problems with overwrite your own base design.

Comment: yes, the preselect is a good idea. I've only used bootstrap when I've used it for everything including all the design elements and styling. If I can preselect just to use the mobile responsive parts, that will be great. Thanks